# Qliksense filter pane formula

Tags: filter, aggregate-functions, countif, qlikview, qliksense

here is my data

```
key2    key1    value
k2_123  k1_1    a
k2_123  k1_2    b
k2_123  k1_3    c
k2_456  k1_4    b
k2_456  k1_5    c
k2_456  k1_6    b
k2_456  k1_7    c
k2_789  k1_8    a
k2_789  k1_9    c
k2_789  k1_10   a
k2_789  k1_11   a
k2_789  k1_12   b
```

i would like to create a filter pane that let me filter on key2 whenever value = 'a'

so the filter pane should give me a list like this

```
key2
k2_123
k2_789
```

how can i do that? should i be using Count + Aggr function?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You only need to use an if() function in the dimension definition.

```
if(value='a',key2)
```

You can use that same if in the script which is likely the largely preferred method but both will work

```
load 
  *, 
  if(value='a',key2) as If_A 
inline [
key2 ,   key1 ,   value
k2_123, k1_1,    a
k2_123,  k1_2,    b
k2_123,  k1_3,    c
k2_456,  k1_4,    b
k2_456,  k1_5,    c
k2_456,  k1_6,    b
k2_456,  k1_7 ,   c
k2_789,  k1_8 ,   a
k2_789,  k1_9 ,   c
k2_789,  k1_10,   a
k2_789,  k1_11 ,  a
k2_789,  k1_12 ,  b
];
```